# Tomcat server automatically stopped in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting the below error.

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000070286c80, pid=496,  tid=6672

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b132) (build 1.8.0-b132)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode windows- amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [jvm.dll+0x116c80]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

Please give the solution

Answer (score 0):

In your logs, you have not the error dump because not enabled.
It looks like a bug of your JRE implementation.

You seem to use an OPEN JDK JRE implementation. If you can, try a more recent version of it or switch to an Oracle JDK/JRE implementation to check if the problem may be corrected.
Anyway, if you cannot change the version of your JDK, you can open a bug in [the bug tracking site of OPEN JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/).

> Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on
>   client versions of Windows

I have two tracks :

- check that you use Open JDK with a aligned version with the Open JRE.
  In theory, it is not necessary but it may be a bug since you use a recent version.
- No guarantee but you can try to enable it by adding the VM argument

`-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash` in your `eclipse.ini` file such as :

```
-vmargs
-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash-Xms256m
```

But don't duplicate the `-vmargs` in the file. You could have more details on the fatal error.